# how import a model from .pb file

Tags: tensorflow2.0

'''

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    model_filename="./model/skipGram-word2Vec/saved_model.pb"
    with gfile.FastGFile(model_filename,'rb') as f:
        graph_def=tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        sess.graph.as_default()
        result=tf.import_graph_def(graph_def,name='')
        print(sess.run(result))
```

'''
then ,the error occured:
DecodeError: Wrong wire type in tag.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can load the model from .pb file in tensorflow 2.0

```
import tensorflow as tf

GRAPH_PB_PATH = './frozen_model.pb'
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
   print("load graph")
   with tf.io.gfile.GFile(GRAPH_PB_PATH,'rb') as f:
       graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
   graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
   sess.graph.as_default()
   tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
   graph_nodes=[n for n in graph_def.node]
   names = []
   for t in graph_nodes:
      names.append(t.name)
   print(names)
```

Comment: @王瑞睿 - Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You.